# angular6 application deployment on IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I have an c# .net application as the back-end, and the front-end was in angular 6, i know that when i use **ng build --prod** to build the angular app, it will generate the required file with hash file name.

Now i would like to host the app in IIS. But when i have a new build on my angular app, i use **ng build --prod** to build, the file name was changed, and i have to replace the file in IIS, any ways to let my IIS to get my new build file automatically?

Comment: After running ng build --prod do you find "dist" folder created in root?

Comment: Yes i found this folder and get the required deployment file, but i want my IIS to update those file automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your right you want a automaticall way to get your new build into your IIS folder and delete the files in there?

The CLI got no way to that automatically. You can append a path with the `--outpu-path` option but that wont clear your old unused files from the IIS folder:

You could try to write some little bat file that deletes the folder in your IIS and moves the files from your build to the IIS folder.

```
SET startFolder="C:\yourpath\to\dist"
SET destinationFolder="\\yourServerOrLocal\pathto\iis"

for %%F in (%destinationFolder%\*.*) do del /s /q /f "%%F" %destinationFolder%

for %%G in (%startFolder%\*.*) do move /Y "%%G" %destinationFolder%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it maybe a solution but i expect a way that can let my IIS can update the file automatically by modified some config or sth. Anyway i will try your solution later, if there are no further answers in this post, i will choose your answer as the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: if it helped you maybe mark my answer as your solution :)